# MacBook Pro Thermal issues

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, performance

I’m having thermal issues with my MacBook Pro 17” late 2011 model laptop I7 2.5 quad core with 16GB of RAM.

Has anyone had any thermal issues when running DAW software on this particular laptop?

Every software app I use: Protools, Logic, Cubase, Live, Maschine, Studio One, all crash if I'm not running an air conditioner in the room. Even then I can’t  use too many plugins.

I think it’s the battery, as the bottom of the laptop gets very hot. I want to remove the battery, However I heard that my processor performance would be compromised.

I was thinking of also removing the DVD drive to get more air into the computer.

If anyone can help with any suggestions or solutions, I would be humbled and thankful for your time and response.

Comment: What condition is the battery in? At six years old, it's ripe for replacement. An app like CoconutBattery will give you information. I imagine the designers laid out appropriate channels and fans for cooling air, and that removing a battery that's supposed to be there would adversely affect airflow.

Comment: Couple of questions:  what is DAW software and do you get a crash or panic report?  If so, can you please add those details to the question?  Removing the battery will have zero effect on performance.  The only thing that will happen is that it will shutdown (uncleanly)  if unplugged.

Answer (score 1):

Spray compressed air back and forth into the exhaust vent in the back of the machine, where the display hinge is located. Do this while the machine is running so that the dislodged dirt will be immediately expelled by the airflow from the fans. Beyond this, nothing should be required.

Comment: I would add that it's quite easy to remove the back cover of this model MBP and it would be beneficial to do so for a good cleaning.  It also wouldn't hurt to remove and clean the heat sink and fan.  Finally, before re-installing the heat sink, add some [high quality thermal paste](http://amzn.to/2zMIwBv) to the CPU (cleaned the old paste off, naturally)

Comment: @Allan it's easy for you and I, but not for the average user, *especially* not heatsink removal. This should be performed by the nearest Apple Store or AASP.

Answer (score 0):

General: I wouldn't run software that "digs" deep like ProTools and others all together. Start them when really needed and Quit them after use: remove them from the LoginItems (with the minus sign underneath the list, then restart).
Battery: in Utilities->SystemInformation select "Power" at the left, Then at the right look at "Condition:" should be "normal", and look at "CycleCount:" should less than 1000. Everything else than I said means *replace battery*
If you take out the battery and run on the charger only, performance is lower and the mac will get even higher.